# Number of Badges off center

Tags: bug, badges, design

The number of badges (the `x insert_number_here`) is usually aligned properly with the corresponding badge name. Now it is offset, being a little too low as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Can we fix this and raise the number of badges a little higher so it is aligned with the badge?